# Alignment is correct in only one element of three

Tags: css, alignment, imagemap

Here is the code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    body { background: #0c2660; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; width: 550; align: center;}
    .logo {text-align: center; margin: 90px 0;  position: relative;}
    .mapper {margin: 0; position: relative;}
    #back { background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; margin: 0px; width: 1024; height: 768px; text-align: center;}
</style>
```

and the html where there is an image map

```
<div id="back">
<div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" width="331" height="74" border="0" alt="" /></div>
<div class="mapper"><img src="greece.png" width="550" height="500" border="0" usemap="#map" class="mapper iborder00aa00 icolor00ff00" alt="" />
<map name="map"></map>
</div>
</div>
```

only the logo image is aligned in the center as it should be, the background image and the greece.png are aligned left no matter what I change

Comment: yg the map contains the area tags which i removed here

Comment: it's working fine for me in chrome and firefox, which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox and tested it in chrome but still a problem

Comment: the problem seems to be the mapper class in the img tag.. when removing it the image aligns (but not the background)

the problem is that this class is necessary for image map to function.. it is the code from the known map js, mapper.js http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/

Comment: the class is generated from the mapper.js - there is no other css or js related to the html

Comment: do u think tables would work?

Comment: Have you looked at the faq for the mapper you're using?http://www.netzgesta.de/cvi/faq.php  contains a question titled "Your script kills the alignment behavior implemented by align="right""

Comment: this is what we do.. we add a div align it but still a problem

Comment: body { background: #0c2660; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px;} 
 .logo { text-align: center; margin: 90px 0; position: relative; } 
 #mapperi { margin-left: 240px; position: relative; align: middle;} 
 #back { background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; margin: 0px; height: 768px; text-align: center; }

Comment: at last..it works
thanks a lot all of you for the help

Comment: Care to post your solution as an answer? I and possibly others would like to know about it, that is what StackOverflow is for :-)

Comment: @Nelson you are right.. i did but not as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the width from `<div id="back">` to get it in the center

Comment: if you want that to be in the center of the browser.I m using FF

Comment: body { background: #0c2660; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; width: 1024; align: center;}
  .logo {text-align: center; margin: 90px 0;  position: relative;}
  .mapper {margin: 0; position: relative;}
  #back { background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; margin: 0px; width: 1024; height: 768px; text-align: center;}

Comment: i did that change but still nothing.. me 2 ff

Comment: body { 
 background: #0c2660; 
 padding: 0px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 }
    .logo {
 text-align: center; 
 margin: 90px 0;  
 position: relative;
 }
    .mapper {
 margin: 0; 
 position: relative;
 }
    #back { 
 background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; 
 margin: 0px; 
 height: 768px; 
 text-align: center;
 }

Comment: still nothing.. this is probably the fault
class="mapper iborder00aa00 icolor00ff00"

i will update soon

Comment: i changed the class to mapperi because class mapper was allready defined but still nothing.. in all browsers
    .mapperi {margin: 0; position: relative;}
    <div class="mapper"><img src="greece.png".......

Comment: body { 
 background: #0c2660; 
 padding: 0px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 1024; 
 } 
 .logo {
 text-align: center; 
 margin: 90px 0; 
 } 
 .mapper {
 margin: 0; 
 text-align: center;
 } 
 #back { 
 background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; 
 margin: 0px; 
 width: 1024; 
 height: 768px; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
   background: #0c2660; 
   padding: 0px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   width: 1024px;
} 
.logo { 
   text-align: center; 
   margin: 90px 0; 
   position: relative; 
}
#mapperi { 
   margin-left: 240px; 
   position: relative; 
   align: middle;
}
#back { 
   background: #0c2660 url('back.jpg') no-repeat; 
   margin: 0px; 
   height: 768px; 
   text-align: center;
}
```

Is the final solution :)